# Tomcat URL mapping individual servlet to root level

Tags: tomcat, mapping

This should be a quickie; just need an answer on short notice...

I'm having to do a bit of maintenance on a webapp deployed under Tomcat 5.5.16 (behind IIS).  It's currently set up with URLs in this format:

http://server.com/myapp/UglyServletName1

...and they just want it to be

http://server.com/Friendly

Obviously the servlet-mapping tag in web.xml isn't enough to map the URL outside of /myapp.  Basically, I just need to know -- is there a trivial way to do this as a url-pattern or similar mapping within Tomcat, or is it easier to do it in IIS (or the Jakarta ISAPI plugin, for that matter)?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Tuckey's URL Rewrite Filter](http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/).